# Bootstrap in Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm using Laravel Homestead (via vagrant on Windows) and my bootstrap isn't working. I know this, because my avatar on my normal php site is in a circle (done with bootstrap) and it isn't in the Laravel site (And also if I copy some code from the bootstrap site, it isn't coming out well too). I'm new to Laravel and I'm under the impression that boostrap is included in Homestead, although I don't have any idea why it's not working then. I tried (just to make shure) adding the css and js from bootstrap in my layout file, but even that doesn't solve the problem. In my site structure I see a bootstrap folder. So, do I need to activate it in some way? Is it the same as for normal Laravel (meaning if you install everything separately instead of using Homestead) and how would I do it?

My layout code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>@yield('title', 'Scorpion To Do')</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a6c4b1e6d8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Like I said, I added the bootstrap css to test it out -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        @if (Route::has('login'))
            <div class="top-right links">
                @auth
                    <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                @else
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                    @endif
                @endauth
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="content">
            <!-- In my normal php site, this avatar is in a round circle, that is how I know bootstrap is not working, because her it is not -->
            <div class="login100-form-avatar">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/images/avatar-01.jpg') }}" alt="AVATAR" />
            </div>

            @yield('content')

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- And also added the js from the bootstrap site -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: What does is say in your network tab for the bootstrap request? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: It seems to load fine in the network tab, and I don't get any errors